# Laravel how to append to paginate eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

I need to modify the paginate eloquent globally

what i need to do is, i need to add

> 'status' => 'success'

to the attributes returned from the paginate response ,

what i did is, in the method inside the controller

```
$data = product::paginate();
return collect(['status' => 'success'])->merge($data);
```

and it works properly

but i need to add the (status) each and every time i use the paginate eloquent in every place in the app

so is there a way to make it globally

Notice i dont have a problem if there is anther way to create a new eloquent called newPaginate() to  solve the poblrem

Comment: What are you doing with the paginated results?

Comment: iam using it for creating APIs

Answer (score 0):

What you are effectively trying to do is edit the `toArray()` method of the `Paginator` class.

How about creating a new `MyPaginator` class which extends the `lengthAwarePaginator` witha  new `toArray()` method?

**App\MyPaginator.php** (or wherever you want to put it)

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;

class MyPaginator extends LengthAwarePaginator
{

  public function __construct(LengthAwarePaginator $paginator) {

    parent::__construct($paginator->items, $paginator->total, $paginator->perPage, $paginator->currentPage, $paginator->options);

  }

  public function toArray() {

      return array_merge(parent::toArray(), ['status'=>'success']);

  }

}
```

**Usage**

```
$data = new MyPaginator(product::paginate());
```

If you need to make this work with other Paginator types, you could extend off `AbstractPaginator` and adjust the constructor accordingly.